# Suppose X has a uniform distribution on the interval (0,a) where a > 0, find P(X>X^2)?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I mainly get stuck with setting up the proper integrals.

Comment: Hint: can you simplify the inequality $X>X^2$?

Answer (score 2):

First consider the inequality...
$X > X^2 \Leftrightarrow 1 > X$.

Therefore, this inequality is only satisfied when $X < 1$.

Then, note that for X to have a uniform distribution on $\left(0, a\right)$, the probability distribution function  must be $f\left(x\right) = \frac{1}{a}, 0 \le x \le a$.

Therefore, $P\left(X > X^2\right) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{a}dx = \frac{1}{a} \int_0^1dx$.

This means that $P\left(X > X^2\right) = \frac{1}{a}\left[x\right]_0^1 = \frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: Your answer started well, but then you got confused.  The answer cannot have an "$X$" in it.  The answer depends on $a$, but not on anything called $X$.  And you're making it needlessly complicated.  The probability of being in the interval $(0,1)$ when uniformly distributed on the larger interval $(0,a)$ is the length of the shorter interval divided by the length of the longer one, so it's $1/a$.  There's no need for integrals.  And you shouldn't be using the same letter, $X$, to refer both to the random variable and to the variable with respect to which you integrate. [continued below]

Comment: I'd use a lower-case $x$ for that: $\int_0^1 \frac1a\,dx=\frac1a \left. x\right|_0^1 = \frac{1-0}{a} = 1/a$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oops that was a silly mishap. Thanks for the fix. (Also, I know the integral was unnecessary, but I thought I'd throw it in since he explicitly mentioned an integral in the question.)

Answer (score 2):

Matt's answer is correct if $a>1$.  Otherwise the answer should be 1.  So the correct answer is $\min(1/a,1)$.

Comment: Great insight; I hadn't considered the event that $a \le 1$...